# Problema consulta MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

No sé cómo devolver cada valor en una variable distinta.

**Mi código:**

```
$query  = "SELECT id_tienda,id_prod from prod_tienda where id_prod='$row' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);           

while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $id = ($mostrar['id_tienda']);   
      echo $id;
```

Comment: Alex, que problema te arroja en pantalla? A simple visto no veo ningún error, excepto esta línea `$id = ($mostrar['id_tienda']);` modifícala por `$id = $mostrar['id_tienda'];` y también debes cerrar tu llaves curvas de tu `while`, es decir, `}`. Podrías también añadir como obtienes la variable `$row` o has un `echo $row;` para confirmar que estas obteniendo correctamente dicho dato.

Comment: el problema es que si la base de datos contiene un valor si lo devuelve si contiene con 2 no funciona ejemplo:                      id_tienda  1  2   id art 1  1    osea el mismo articulo para 2 tiendas diferentes pero no puedo devolver cada id de tienda en una variable diferente para usarlas mas tarde

Comment: Alex bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Al leer tu comentario, pienso que posiblemente tengas un error de lógica. Cuando tú haces un `SELECT` puedes luego obtener los resultados de diferentes maneras. Si dices que necesitas varios valores, entonces lo que tienes que devolver es un array con todos los resultados y tratar ese array en el lugar donde necesitas mostrar los datos. Así que el `echo $id;` dentro del `while` no te sirve de nada en este caso. Por otra parte, quiero señalarte que esta consulta: `SELECT id_tienda,id_prod from prod_tienda where id_prod='$row'` es vulnerable a inyección de código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Un posible ejemplo:*

```
$query  = "SELECT id_tienda,id_prod FROM prod_tienda WHERE id_prod='$row'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);        

//Comprobamos si existe registro. 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {   
    //Tu array con los datos desde la Base de Datos.    
    $mostrar  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);        
} else {
    echo 'No se encontraron datos.';
}
```

> **Nota:** te aconsejo por seguridad utilizar sentencias [mysqli prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO.](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) También te aconsejo leer bien
>   [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: muchisimas gracias me sirvio mucho , buen trabajo

Comment: @alextiberiuTelegaru de nada amig@. Si la respuesta te ha solucionado el problema puedes aceptarla y obtienes tus primeros puntos. Aquí mas información https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas